# Doing boolean OR query string in sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I was just wondering if in sunspot solr we could do a search with the following logic:

keyword = orange OR red orange OR blue green

Thanks in advance for any inputs

Comment: Nope, if I put in a keyword as "orange OR red" then it simply searches for the phrase.

Comment: I have posted a similar question here. please do answer this if anybody knows - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005661/how-to-do-simple-boolean-query-in-sunspot-solr

Answer (score 2):

keywords("orange red blue"){minimum_match 1} will search for keyword = orange or red or blue.

the [sunspot fulltext docs](http://sunspot.github.com/docs/Sunspot/DSL/Fulltext.html) have a couple other methods to alter your search.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little bit vague of an explanation now, but it seems that sunspot solr enables you to adjust the search params before querying solr itself. I would update this answer once I get some time on my hands to work on this problem again.