# How to do simple boolean query in sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, search-engine, sunspot-rails

```
>>> marketing = User.search do |s|
>>>     s.fulltext "Marketing"
>>> end
>>> marketing.total
1448

>>> sales = User.search do |s|
>>>     s.fulltext "Sales"
>>> end
>>> sales.total
567

>>> marketing_and_sales = User.search do |s|
>>>     s.fulltext "Marketing AND Sales"
>>> end
>>> marketing_and_sales.total
945

>>> marketing_or_sales = User.search do |s|
>>>     s.fulltext "Marketing OR Sales"
>>> end
>>> marketing_or_sales.total
945  

<Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:User"], :q=>"Marketing AND Sales", :fl=>"* score",      :qf=>"textfield1 textfield2 textfield3", :defType=>"dismax", :start=>0, :rows=>30}>
```

I want simple boolean queries to get working on sunspot-rails, solr
I tried many possibilities its not simply taking it.

The AND and NOT seems to be working as per the dismax configuration.
How can i make OR query working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. You can specify the scope of the search criterias using any_of and all_of . though all_of doesnt work unless used inside any_of . here is the link http://sunspot.github.com/docs/Sunspot/DSL/Scope.html#all_of-instance_method

```
>>> marketing_or_sales = User.search do |s|
>>>     s.any_of do 
>>>         s.fulltext "Marketing"
>>>         s.fulltext "Sales"
>>>     end
>>> end
>>> marketing_or_sales.total
945
```

Comment: Does it really work for you? The doc claims that any_of and all_of only works for scalar fields, eg. string, integer etc. From my observation there is no difference between call any_of or all_of for fulltext fields. The query is the same, so in fact sunspot just ignores any_of or all_of for fulltext fields.